# How to format ranges including negative values in tables?

Tags: formatting, tables

I am working on a research paper where I am trying to format values in a table:
From −0.2 to −0.14. Is this formatting correct?

```
-0.2 - -0.14
```

Another question:
From −3 to 3. Is this correct?

```
-3-3
```

Comment: Is this really an Academia question as defined by the charter? (It's a reasonable question for a discussion more focused on LaTeX and related...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to use the right kind of dashes. Most computer typesetting or word processing programs, including MS Word, LaTeX, support hypens, minus signs, en-dashes and em-dashes at the very least. The en-dash is usually used to give a range of numbers. I've tried to reproduce the way you would write this in LaTeX, but this particular StackExchange site doesn't appear to support MathJax which allows for inline LaTeX on websites.

$$
-0.2 -- -0.14
$$

and

$$ 
-3 -- 3
$$

Edited to add: The MathJax above might be a bit misleading. In a LaTeX table cell, I would probably write `-3.5 -- 12.3` or whatever. I would probably use `\text{}` around it in math mode to prevent the dashes from being treated as unary minuses and allow the double-dash to become an en-dash. The numbers will render the same regardless. Neither of these things work well in MathJax, but they do something reasonable in true LaTeX files.

Comment: And if the OP has to format many values and ranges in LaTeX, I also suggest the usage of the package "siunitx" for a consistent management of the format throughout the paper.

Comment: The word "LaTeX" is extraordinarily misleading.  MathJax makes it possible to use both inline and displayed mathematical notation, using approximately the same kind of code that is used for mathematical notation in LaTeX.  But LaTeX is a full-fledged and sophisticated word processor, and most of a typical LaTeX document, and not unusually all of it, is not in mathematical notation and does not involve code set between dollar signs.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yeah, though if MathJax worked here like it does on other SE sites, I could have given a reasonable approximation of what OP should use. I would have probably needed to wrap it in an `\rm{}`, but that's OK, and I would have figured it out while posting. I forget how LaTeX renders number ranges in math mode, but I would have gotten it right eventually.

Comment: LaTeX does not render number ranges in math mode, but users render such things using LaTeX.  That's a matter of language.  Mathematicians may write "for $i=1,\ldots,n$" or "for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$" and confused non-mathematicians sometimes write "for all $i=1,\ldots,n$", and LaTeX renders it in each case.  And when one posts to math.stackexchange.com, one sees lots and lots of people using MathJax the way children on the Linkletter show speak English. For that "reasonable approximation", maybe just linking to something on math.stackexchange.com could suffice.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, maybe you could link to an example instead if you're going to be picky.

Comment: If what were asked for is merely examples of what MathJax does, or what LaTeX in math mode does, then [something like this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338121/evaluate-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-left-frac13n4-frac23n4/338125#338125) might serve.  However, although I've used MathJax and LaTeX for expressing ranges of numbers in several formats, I think for a "table" of the sort suggested, I would put only the numerals themselves in math mode; the rest I would probably do along the lines of GEdgar's answer.

Comment: . . . and the main reason for using MathMode for the numerals themselves would be so that the minus signs would look like proper minus signs rather than like hyphens and the decimal points would get formatted correctly.  Minus signs that look like hyphens instead of minus signs look like something an illiterate would write (and journalists do it incessantly).

Comment: @MichaelHardy, the real point of the answer was to show that typically en-dashes are used for ranges and sometimes other symbols are used for horizontal lines. Feel free to upvote the answer you prefer. I +1ed the two answers that suggest alternatives, as well.

Comment: I wouldn't actually use the notation suggested in this answer because it's too easy to confuse the en-dash with the minus sign.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, maybe you could have started with that comment then? Instead of lecturing me on how the word LaTeX was confusing?

Comment: If I had started with that comment I would still have written the comment on the other topic, the fact that misleading people about what LaTeX is could be avoided.  You and others could benefit from my saying that.  Is there some problem with such a contribution from me?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, "extraordinarily misleading" was a bit strong in my opinion. The use of "LaTeX" to represent the concept that MathJax supports some subset of a LaTeX-like mathematical notation is extremely common, and your objection is overly pedantic in my opinion. This is especially true since the `\text{}` operator from amsmath works in MathJax and gives the representation I really wanted rather than the math mode  representation while in MathJax's normal mode. Thus, it's closer to a LaTeX rendering which is all I really wanted to give a picture of.

Comment: \text{} does _not_ work with the kind of thing you were writing about: you can't do en-dashes in the normal way in MathJax. It is indeed extremely common to call MathJax "LaTeX", and that's one reason why I thought it was important to mention this.  It is also extraordinarily misleading: What if someone learns MathJax and then tries to use LaTeX under the impression that that's what they had learned?  They'd be hopelessly lost.  I thought you and others would find my comment helpful.  I never suspected that anyone would consider it anything but friendly, but now I do suspect that.

Comment: The en-dash is not mathematics per se, and therefore it does not belong inside the math delimiters.  The correct TeX syntax is $-3$--$3$.  However, the actual correct solution is to **use different notation**, like $(-3, 3)$ or $-3 \le x \le 3$ or "between $-3$ and $3$".

Comment: @JeffE : How about the following expression.  How would you deal with it without \text{} inside the math delimiters?  I encounter similar things daily.  $$A = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if the Gauss--Markov assumptions hold}, \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, saying someone is being "extraordinarily misleading" reads like an accusation of wrong doing, if you can't see that, you need to recalibrate your reading and writing filter. Also, "hopelessly lost" is another extreme statement that seems unlikely to me. I write things in MathJax all the time that I learned from LaTeX and find the translation pretty reasonable. It's hard to refer back to numbered equations, and a few other things, but MathJax is surprisingly LaTeX like. The fact that you think that average learners of MathJax will have no hope of learning LaTeX is telling.

Comment: @JeffE, I swear I went over to ComputationalScience.SE where MathJax is enabled and got what I wanted out of `\text{}`, but I guess I was wrong. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @BillBarth : You say you learned LaTeX first.  But if someone had learned MathJax while under the impression that it was LaTeX, that would be a completely different situation when they first tried LaTeX without suspecting that it was different from MathJax.  They'd be lost and they'd have to start learning LaTeX after they thought they already knew it. I didn't say they'd have no hope of learning it; rather it would be hopeless to think they could use it as if they already knew it, as they thought they did.

Comment: @BillBarth : I haven't been on the computational science site on SE but I post every day to the math site.  On that site you cannot code en-dashes within \text{} in the way you would in LaTeX.

Comment: The phrase "extraordinarily misleading" was not meant to imply that misleading was being done deliberately, but only that a person trying to use LaTeX under the mistaken impression that they knew it because they knew MathJax would be extraordinarily misled.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, but you might understand how your language here has been pretty accusatory since I can't see your intent from here. Hopelessly lost certainly sounds pretty hopeless to me. I agree that learning LaTeX is more than learning MathJax, but I never said it wasn't, I just said that people use LaTeX as a shorthand for the style of notation that's available in MathJax. There's no big danger here. Also, see my edit.

Comment: @JeffE, do you think that a range notation with parens or words is a good idea for compact table which the OP is really asking about? I agree in other contexts, but I couldn't make it work nicely for me in a big table of ranges. Admittedly a big table of ranged numbers is probably a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: @BillBarth I would try separate columns for the upper and lower bounds, and if that was ugly, I would seriously reconsider having a table full of ranges at all.

Comment: **Please take extended conversation to [chat].**

Answer (score 20):

Personally, I would definitely not use this type of formatting, as I think it is easy for people to confuse the various different types of dashes.  Instead, I would recommend using [the bracket format typically used for denoting intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals). Formatted in this manner, your examples would be:

> [-0.2, -0.14]
>
> [-3, 3]

Comment: Was just going to mention this. Definitely less ambiguous, especially if coupled with parens for exclusive intervals.

Comment: This depends a lot on audience. The bracket/paren notation is excellently unambiguous *for those familiar with it.* That’s going to depend on field/audience.

Answer (score 19):

If using symbols causes confusion, then don't use symbols.  Use words.  For example, "-0.2 to -0.14" and "-3 to 3".

Comment: This is what the [SI guide](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf) recommends:'this *Guide* strongly recommends that the word “to” be used to indicate a range of 
values for a quantity instead of a range dash'. +1

Answer (score 0):

In order to cover all possible ranges (including negative) without confusion, I think that using either *parentheses*, or *brackets*, is much better than using any kinds of dashes. That is, for scientific data values. However, for those as well as for other types of values and their ranges, I would highly suggest consulting your *publication style guide*, which should take precedence over someone's preference. While, typically, style guides don't have strict rules on the subject, there might be some differences in that regard between publication styles, especially for some special cases, such as date ranges and page number ranges. For more details and some examples, see [this blog post](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2014/06/comparing-mla-and-apa-numbers.html).